# Replace Create Trigger with Foreign Key (RI)

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, foreign-keys

Create Trigger:

```
SELECT @oldVersionId = (SELECT DISTINCT VERSION_ID FROM Deleted)
    SELECT @newVersionId = (SELECT DISTINCT VERSION_ID FROM Inserted)
    SELECT @appId = (SELECT DISTINCT APP_ID FROM Deleted)

UPDATE [TableName]
SET [VERSION_ID] = @newVersionId
WHERE (([VERSION_ID] = @oldVersionId) AND ([APP_ID] = @appId) )
```

Can this Trigger be replace with a Foreign Key to update the VERSION_ID ?

What I think could be a problem is the AND condition, how to express that in a FK with On del/update Cascade?

Comment: I want to get rid of that trigger and replace it with a FK constraint. When PK ID changes cascade that change on another FK ID table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot really tell you what you're looking for - you're too unclear in your question.

But basically, if two tables are linked via a foreign key constraint, of course you can add a clause to that to make sure the child table gets updated when the parents table's PK changes:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ChildTable
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ChildTable_ParentTable
FOREIGN KEY(ChildTableColumn) REFERENCES dbo.ParentTable(PKColumn)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

The `ON UPDATE CASCADE` does exactly that - if the referenced column (the `PKColumn` in `ParentTable`) changes, then the FK constraint will "cascade" that update down into the child table and update it's `ChildTableColumn` to match the new `PKColumn`

Read [all about cascading referential integrity constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx) and what options you have on MSDN Books Online

Answer (score 1):

*FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS* don't update anything.  They check the values being written to a record and cause the write to fail if they cause a constraint to fail.

Also, as @marc_s points out in his comment, triggers in MS SQL Server are set based.  The `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables can hold multiple records at once.  Your code only works for one record.

You could try something along these lines...

```
UPDATE
  table
SET
  VERSION_ID = inserted.VERSION_ID
FROM
  table
INNER JOIN
  deleted
    ON  table.VERSION_ID = deleted.VERSION_ID
    AND table.APP_ID     = deleted.APP_ID
INNER JOIN
  inserted
    ON deleted.PRIMARY_KEY = inserted.PRIMARY_KEY
```

**EDIT**

I just read your comment, and I think I understand.  You want a foreign key constraint with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

You use this format to create that with DDL.

```
ALTER TABLE DBO.<child table>
ADD CONSTRAINT <foreign key name> FOREIGN KEY <child column>
REFERENCES DBO.<parent table>(<parent column>)
{ON [DELETE|UPDATE] CASCADE}
```

Or you could just SQL Server Management Studio to set it up.  Just make sure the ON UPDATE CASCADE is present.